# TypeError 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, pandas-groupby, data-manipulation

I created a function and use it in a for loop but got **TypeError 'DataFrame' object is not callable**

```
def Freq(df, keyvar, *args):
    Freq = pd.DataFrame({'Frequency': df.groupby([*args])[keyvar].count()}).reset_index()
    Freq['Percent'] = (Freq['Frequency']/sum(Freq['Frequency'])*100).round(2)
    Freq['Cumulative Frequency'] = Freq['Frequency'].cumsum()
    Freq['Cumulative Percent'] = (Freq['Cumulative Frequency']/sum(Freq['Frequency'])*100).round(2)
    return Freq
```

And I used this `Freq()` on:

```
freq_var = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
for col in freq_var:
    Freq = Freq(data, 'KEYS', f'{col}')
    print(f'============ {col} frequency table ============\n{Freq}\n\n')


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-2d4041b2961b> in <module>()
      1 freq_var = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
      2 for col in freq_var:
----> 3     Freq = Freq(data, 'KEYS', f'{col}')
      4     print(f'============ {col} frequency table ============\n{Freq}\n\n')

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

If I did not call `Freq()` and typed directly, it was fine without error and output successfully.

```
for col in freq_var:
    Freq = pd.DataFrame({'Frequency': data.groupby([col])['KEYS'].count()}).reset_index()
    Freq['Percent'] = (Freq['Frequency']/sum(Freq['Frequency'])*100).round(2)
    Freq['Cumulative Frequency'] = Freq['Frequency'].cumsum()
    Freq['Cumulative Percent'] = (Freq['Cumulative Frequency']/sum(Freq['Frequency'])*100).round(2) 
    print(f'============ {col} frequency table ============\n{Freq}\n\n')
```

Does anyone know the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't name your variable the same as your function name. You're essentially overwriting your function with a DataFrame, so by the time your second iteration happens `Freq` is a dataframe instead of the function you think it is.

```
freq_var = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
for col in freq_var:
    freq_df = Freq(data, 'KEYS', f'{col}')
    print(f'============ {col} frequency table ============\n{freq_df}\n\n')
```